# If we don't know the number of entries then how to stop a input() loop of while or for

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, input, while-loop

I tried to get input by bigger number entries but it says "index out of range"

if we don't know the number of entries then how to stop a input() loop of while or for, in python:

```
while():
 listMatch.append(input())
```

Look what if I have:

```
Djokovic:Murray:2-6,6-7,7-6,6-3,6-1 
Murray:Djokovic:6-3,4-6,6-4,6-3 
Djokovic:Murray:6-0,7-6,6-7,6-3 
Murray:Djokovic:6-4,6-4 
Djokovic:Murray:2-6,6-2,6-0 
Murray:Djokovic:6-3,4-6,6-3,6-4 
Djokovic:Murray:7-6,4-6,7-6,2-6,6-2 
Murray:Djokovic:7-5,7-5 
Williams:Muguruza:3-6,6-3,6-3
```

AND

```
Halep:Raonic:2-6,6-7,7-6,6-3,6-1
Kerber:Raonic:6-3,4-6,6-4,6-3
Raonic:Wawrinka:6-0,7-6,6-7,6-3
Wawrinka:Raonic:6-4,6-4
Halep:Raonic:2-6,6-2,6-0
Wawrinka:Raonic:6-3,4-6,6-3,6-4
Raonic:Wawrinka:7-6,4-6,7-6,2-6,6-2
Wawrinka:Kerber:7-5,7-5
Halep:Kerber:3-6,6-3,6-3
Halep:Wawrinka:0-6,0-6,6-0,6-0,7-5
Kerber:Wawrinka:6-3,4-6,7-6,0-6,7-5
```

Here I don't know how many entries I want to enter. In above examples there are 9 and 11.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This loop will stop as soon as you just press return (no string entered)

```
listMatch=[]

while True:
    z=input()
    if z:
        listMatch.append(z)
    else:
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

add a control loop that checks for input:

```
listMatch =[]
while(True):
    input_value = input()
    if(input_value == '' or  input_value == 'quit'): 
        break
    listMatch.append(input_value)
```

if no text or quit is entered, loop will break

Answer (score 0):

```
listMatch = []

while True:
    # get the user's input
    stuff = input()

    # if they typed "quit", stop looping
    if stuff == 'quit':
        break

    # otherwise append their input to the list and keep on looping
    listMatch.append(stuff)
```